# Combining FutureProviders using a FutureProvider RiverPod

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-provider, riverpod

I am currently making the Udacity Sunshine project in Flutter. I have two different provider to fetch current temperature and daily forecasts.

I want to combine the two providers and make a new single provider called weatherProvider.

**File: weather_data.dart**

```
import 'package:app/models/current_weather_data.dart';

import 'one_call_weather_data.dart';

class WeatherData {
  final OneCallWeatherData oneCallWeatherData;
  final CurrentWeatherData currentWeatherData;

  WeatherData({
    required this.oneCallWeatherData,
    required this.currentWeatherData,
  });
}
```

**File:weather_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:app/models/current_weather_data.dart';
import 'package:app/models/one_call_weather_data.dart';
import 'package:app/services/weather.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

var oneCallWeatherProvider = FutureProvider<OneCallWeatherData>((ref) async {
  return await WeatherService.getOneCallWeatherData();
});

var currentWeatherProvider = FutureProvider<CurrentWeatherData>((ref) async {
  return await WeatherService.getCurrentWeatherData();
});

final weatherProvider = FutureProvider<WeatherData>((ref) async {
  final currentWeatherData = ref.watch(currentWeatherProvider);

  final onecallWeatherData = ref.watch(oneCallWeatherProvider);

 // How to return WeatherData here??
});
```

In above providers, I am trying to fetch the data from two future providers and get the objects for currentWeatherData and onecallWeatherData. I would like to wait for them here and get the two data. The two data sends error if error as well. Now, how to send the data  to UI from the provider so that I can do `.when(data:xx, error: xx, loading: xx)` on the widget and get both data safely?

**Note:** I can get the whole data without combining the providers by making a single FutureProvider and awaiting the two futures using `Future.wait()`. However, I am trying to learn to combine the providers. So, any solution from the community is greatly apprecitated.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `provider.future` to obtain a `Future` which you can then await

This allows you to write:

```dart
final weatherProvider = FutureProvider<WeatherData>((ref) async {
  final currentWeatherData = ref.watch(currentWeatherProvider.future);
  final onecallWeatherData = ref.watch(oneCallWeatherProvider.future);

  return WeatherData(
    oneCallWeatherData: await onecallWeatherData,
    currentWeatherData: await currentWeatherData,
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in this way.

##### Example:

```dart
final weatherProvider = FutureProvider<WeatherData>((ref) async {
  final currentWeatherData = ref.watch(currentWeatherProvider);
  final onecallWeatherData = ref.watch(oneCallWeatherProvider);

  return WeatherData(
    oneCallWeatherData: onecallWeatherData,
    currentWeatherData: currentWeatherData,
  );
});
```